# Access file from the app folder in uwp

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Directory:

```
App1
  - MainPage.xaml.cs
  - Sample.xaml
```

im trying to do is getting the xaml content from the sample as a string but it doesnt work since it cant find the file:

```
    var x = Path.GetFullPath(@"sample.xaml");
    FileStream s = new FileStream(x, FileMode.Open);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this give it a try.

> Save your file in a location eg (Assets Folder)Now, make sure that the
>   build action is set to Content.

```
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/youfile.xaml"));
```

The StorageFile you get is of course read-only, but it can be passed to any API that expects a StorageFile.

If you want to read you can try.

```
  var result = storageFile.OpenReadAsync()
```

[StorageFile Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile)

Comment: Indeed but the xaml is compiled...damn

Comment: I think if you set build action to content it will not compile

Comment: Should I even do this?

Comment: I see, testing it out now : )

Comment: wow man thank you so much! Any way to give you some extra points? : )

Answer (score 1):

The source files (.xaml, .cs) are compiled, and in the deployed app they do not exist as physical files, so you can't open them this way.

Comment: oh crap. So does that mean there is no way to dynamically load xaml files using the xamlreader?

Comment: There is a way, for example you can set the Build Action of the XAML file to "Content" and possibly set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always". This way the XAML will not be compiled and you cannot access it normally from other classes

Comment: @Jogy Yes i also think it can be used as resources in the app